# how to apply custom CSS to select row into Tree Grid Panel into Ext JS 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, treegrid, treepanel

I am new into ext js  I am using Ext js 4.1 for Create `treeGrid` Panel also we use different render function for ech column. Then How to apply CSS to Selected Row into `Treepanel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected raw css class is `x-grid-row-selected`, which you can override:

```
.x-grid-row-selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Within your renderer you can apply a css class using metadata:

```
renderer: function( aValue, aMetaData, aRecord )
{
    aMetaData.tdCls = 'some-of-your-own';
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, it's usually not a good idea to override existing CSS classes if you can add your own instead. It's hard to guarantee that your changes won't bleed over into other components. The second option is better; adding your own classes via `tdCls` gives you more flexibility and allows you to selectively apply styles where you need them.